# Python Normalization results in 1s insted of range 0-1

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I am trying to normalize my data using Python `sklearn` `preprocessing.normalize`, but almast all the results end as `1` insted of in range `[0-1]` . I guess it is simple mistake, but I am new to Python. The biggest difference is visible in average, which clearly shows something is way off!

Here is example code to reproduce the problem

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

tmp = np.random.randint(0, 100, 1000) 

tmp_st = preprocessing.normalize(tmp.reshape(-1, 1))
print('min: ' + str(min(tmp_st)) + 
      ' | max: ' + str(max(tmp_st)) + 
      ' | avg: ' + str(sum(tmp_st) / len(tmp_st)) + 
      ' - min org: ' + str(min(tmp)) + 
      ' | max org: ' + str(max(tmp)) + 
      ' | avg org: ' + str(sum(tmp) / len(tmp)))
# min: 0.0 | max: 1.0 | avg: 0.99 - min org: 0 | max org: 99 | avg org: 50.156
```

Also I have tried to do it in Data Frame

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame({'tmp': tmp})
df_tmp['tmp_st'] = preprocessing.normalize(df_tmp[['tmp']])
print('min: ' + str(min(df_tmp['tmp_st'])) + 
      ' | max: ' + str(max(df_tmp['tmp_st'])) + 
      ' | avg: ' + str(sum(df_tmp['tmp_st']) / len(df_tmp['tmp_st'])) + 
      ' - min org: ' + str(min(df_tmp['tmp'])) + 
      ' | max org: ' + str(max(df_tmp['tmp'])) + 
      ' | avg org: ' + str(sum(df_tmp['tmp']) / len(df_tmp['tmp'])))
# min: 0.0 | max: 1.0 | avg: 0.99 - min org: 0 | max org: 99 | avg org: 50.156
```

Answer (score 0):

`normalize` by default normalizes each row independently. But you're giving it a column vector — each row only has one value! Try adding the `axis=0` keyword arg to normalize by column instead.

Comment: I have tried `axis = 0`, but the result still is odd:  
`min: [0.] | max: [0.05490838] | avg: [0.02733495] - min org: 0 | max org: 99 | avg org: 49.285` 
The same with `axis = 1`:  
min: 0.0 | max: 1.0 | avg: 0.991 - min org: 0 | max org: 99 | avg org: 49.2851